# How to read several ADCs interfaces every n seconds per channel in STM32 MCU?

Tags: adc, arm, stm32f0

I'm using the ADC channels (12-bit resolution) of a STM32F0 microcontroller to read voltage values in three different points of a board. What I want to do is to read the values every 2 seconds (I have 2 seconds to read the values in the three points) and send them by the UART interface. In order to select which ADC channel I'm reading I'm implementing the voltage reading functions as follows:

```
uint16_t readv1(void){
    //Here I try to read ADC_CHANNEL_1
    //chConfig and txtbuff are global variables:
    //ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef chConfig;
    //char txtbuff[64];

    chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    uint32_t vref = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    uint16_t vref2 = (uint16_t) vref;
    sprintf(TextBuffer, "%u\n", vref2);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*)txtbuff, strlen(txtbuff), 0xFFFFFFFF);

    return vref2;
}
```

This is the function for scanning one ADC channel. For reading the other two ADC channels I'm using the same procedure just changing the value of `n` in the line `chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_n;` where `n` is the channel number. Note that `chConfig` is of the same type of `sConfig` declared in `MX_ADC_Init()` function, but `chConfig` is a global variable.

The problem I have is that `readv1` function reads a constant voltage (I have checked it with a voltimeter) but the numbers showed in the terminal via UART change a lot, between 120 and 2400. I'm not sure if using the line `chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;` for selecting a channel is good or if there is any other procedure to follow. Or should I use polling mode as follows every time I need to read a single channel?

```
    chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
    chConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_239CYCLES_5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    uint32_t vref = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
```

In order to scan the ADC every two seconds I'm using a 8 MHz timer as follows:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
    if (htim->Instance==TIM3){
        //Here I call the functions which read the voltage values of different ADC channels
        volt1 = readv1();
        readv2(volt1);
        readv3(volt1);
    }
}
```

This is the main function where I initialize the periphericals (ADC is in interruption mode):

```
int main(void)
{

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART4_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  }
}
```

And below are the initialization functions for the timer and the ADC:

```
/* TIM3 init function */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 8000;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 1999;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}


/* ADC init function */
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_239CYCLES_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

**Update:** I have updated the code with the modifications I proposed before. Now I get a stable value but is very low. I have confirmed that I'm always reading the same ADC channel, the instructions I'm coding are not changing the ADC channel before doing the read.
Below is the whole code with the modifications:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "string.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart4;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
char txtbuff[64];
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef chConfig;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_USART4_UART_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
uint16_t readv1(void);
void readv1(uint16_t);
void readv2(uint16_t);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
    uint16_t volt1;
    if (htim->Instance==TIM3){
        //Here I call the functions which read the voltage values of different ADC channels
        volt1 = readv1();
        readv2(volt1);
        readv3(volt1);
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_USART4_UART_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI14;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI14State = RCC_HSI14_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI14CalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* ADC init function */
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/* TIM3 init function */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 8000;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 1999;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/* USART4 init function */
static void MX_USART4_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart4.Instance = USART4;
  huart4.Init.BaudRate = 57600;
  huart4.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart4.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart4.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart4.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart4.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart4.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart4.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart4.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8 
                          |GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11 
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1 
                          |GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PE2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE3 PE4 PE0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC14 PC15 PC7 PC8 
                           PC9 PC10 PC11 PC12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8 
                          |GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PF9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB12 PB13 PB14 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD8 PD9 PD10 PD11 
                           PD12 PD13 PD0 PD1 
                           PD3 PD4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11 
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1 
                          |GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA8 PA15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

uint16_t readv1(void){
    //Here I try to read ADC_CHANNEL_1
    //chConfig and txtbuff are global variables:
    //ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef chConfig;
    //char txtbuff[64];

    chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
    chConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    uint32_t v = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    uint16_t vm = (uint16_t) v;
    sprintf(txtbuff, "%u\n", vm);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*)txtbuff, strlen(txtbuff), 0xFFFFFFFF);

    return vm;
}


void readv2(uint16_t volt1){
    //Here I try to read ADC_CHANNEL_2
    //chConfig and txtbuff are global variables:
    //ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef chConfig;
    //char txtbuff[64];

    chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
    chConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    uint32_t v = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    uint16_t vm = ((uint16_t) v / volt1)*3300;
    sprintf(txtbuff, "%u\n", vm);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*)txtbuff, strlen(txtbuff), 0xFFFFFFFF);

}

void readv3(uint16_t volt1){
    //Here I try to read ADC_CHANNEL_4
    //chConfig and txtbuff are global variables:
    //ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef chConfig;
    //char txtbuff[64];

    chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
    chConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    uint32_t v = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);
    uint16_t vm = ((uint16_t) v / volt1)*3300;
    sprintf(txtbuff, "%u\n", vm);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*)txtbuff, strlen(txtbuff), 0xFFFFFFFF);
}


/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif
```

Comment: In your 1st code snippet, you're not actually performing an A2D conversion - so not reality surprising you're seeing the same value. The 2nd snippet looks like it would do the job.

Comment: readv2(volt1)?  You're passing what argument exactly?

Comment: @brhans He does not have to start and stop a  conversion; he is using continuous conversion mode. So whenever he pulls Get_value ; he should get it in theory.

Comment: @ammar.cma, I'm passing `uint16_t volt1` which is a reference value measured by `volt1 = readv1();`.

Comment: @ammar.cma whenever the code executes `HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);` it should get the value, but how can I tell from which ADC channel it is taking it?

Comment: The best way to know that is if you debug the code line by line.

Comment: Why are you passing a reference value to another read ADC function?

Comment: @ammar.cma because within those other ADC read functions I use the reference to put in scale the measured values before sending them through the UART.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? Like everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last update I posted I was trying to read the ADC channels in polling mode but what I actually needed was to read the ADC in interrupt mode.

Finally, I solved the problem by modifying the functions as follows (I show for `readv1` function):

```
uint16_t readv1(void){
    chConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
    chConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);

    // Then I replaced the HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc); instruction by the following one:
    HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc);
    // This starts the ADC in interrupt mode

    HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc);

    // I deleted the HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 0xFFFFFFFF); instruction as I'm not using polling working mode

    uint32_t v = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);

    // I replaced the HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc); instruction by the following one:
    HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&hadc);
    // This stops the ADC working in interrupt mode

    chConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_NONE;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &chConfig);

    uint16_t vm = (uint16_t) v;
    sprintf(TextBuffer, "%u\n", vm);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*)txtbuff, strlen(txtbuff), 0xFFFFFFFF);    

    return vm;
}
```

I did the same modifications in `readv2` and `readv3` functions. Actually, as I'm using the same procedure for reading all the ADC channels I created a function which receives as parameter the channel number.